# App crashes when trying to dismiss loading view

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a weather app and I make a network call every time the user's location updates, which is just every time the app launches.

I am also presenting a loading view while the information is fetched for a better user experience, but about 1 in 10 times the app launches, it crashes when trying to remove the background view of the loading view from the superview and I have no idea why.

Edit: I've tried making the containerView optional and it solves the crashes, but the loading view stays up forever since the containerView isn't dismissed in these cases.

I will attach the code to the data loading class and the call site below if anyone wants to help me with it.

Thank you in advance for you time!

```
class WEDataLoadingVC: UIViewController {

var containerView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
}


func presentLoadingView() {
    containerView = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    view.addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    containerView.alpha = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { self.containerView.alpha = 0.8 }
    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .large)
    containerView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.centerX(in: containerView, constant: 0)
    activityIndicator.centerY(in: containerView, constant: 0)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}

func dismissLoadingView() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.containerView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.containerView = nil
    }
}
```

and the call site

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location = locations.last else { return /* present alert */}
    let lat = String(location.coordinate.latitude)
    let lon = String(location.coordinate.longitude)
    LocationManager.shared.getLocationName(for: location) { placemark in
        guard let place = placemark?.locality else {
            /* present alert*/
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async { self.locationView.update(with: place) }
    }
    presentLoadingView()
    NetworkManager.shared.getWeatherDataFor(lat: lat, lon: lon) { [weak self] result in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.dismissLoadingView()
        switch result {
        case .success(let data):
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.currentConditionsView.update(with: data)
                self.lookAheadView.update(with: data)
                self.todayView.update(with: data)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            /* present alert */
            print(error.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error message?  Stack trace?

Comment: if you mention error message as well and on which line its crashing might be it'll become more easy to find out issue

Comment: are you sure didUpdateLocations is called only once? Because it should be called every time a position changes, which leads to a lot of race problems in your code

Comment: Is it possible for `dismissLoadingView` to be called twice in a row?  If so, you should check for whether `containerView` is nil.  In fact, since you are setting it to nil, you should probably declare it as `UIView?` and write the tests when it's used.

Comment: The error appears on the line that removes containerView from the superview in the dismissLoadingView() function. I have also tried making containerView optional, but in the cases where it would crash before, now the loading view isn't removed from the superview anymore. There isn't any other call for this function besides the one in the code provided.

Comment: NOT SURE ,  Looks like the issue of multiple times showing the loading view because of location manager will several times (on starting itself)  and from  multiple threads accessing the same view  you may get BAD_ACCESS error

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing below :

```
var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView

func presentLoadingView() {
    if containerView == nil {
        containerView = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        view.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        containerView.alpha = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { self.containerView.alpha = 0.8 }
        activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .large)
        containerView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.centerX(in: containerView, constant: 0)
        activityIndicator.centerY(in: containerView, constant: 0)
    }
    else { 
        self.containerView.isHidden = false
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }
}

func dismissLoadingView() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        self.containerView.isHidden = true
   }
}
```